# The use of brackets in javascript arrow function declaration

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

In ES6/ES2015 arrow functions can be declared with or without brackets around the parameter.

ie:

```
var foo_1 = myVar => {
  return myVar + 1;
}
```

or:

```
var foo_2 = (myVar) => {
  return myVar + 2;
}
```

What I would like to know is:
what is the difference (if any)?

Comment: There is no. If there is only one argument you can use either. PS: those are "parentheses", not "brackets"

Comment: This is a parameter btw, not a property.

Comment: The purpose of brackets in closure is just that you can have multiple arguments. There's no diff in your sample..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no differences in your example.

You *need* parentheses if you

- have no parameter: `() => ...`
- have multiple parameters: `(foo, bar) => ...`
- use destructuring: `({foo}) => ...`
- use default values: `(foo = 42) => ...`
- have a rest parameter: `(...bar) => ...`
- have any combination of the above

In other words, whenever you do not have a single identifier-only parameter.

Comment: `foo_1.toString() != foo_2.toString()` is the only difference to come up with :-)